# Translations and Primary Sources for Poncelet, Desargues, and Kepler

Tags: math-history, projective-geometry

I am currently researching classic projective geometry. Ideally, I would like side-by-side translations of the following books/publications, although any translations into English and primary sources of the documents would be appreciated:

- Kepler, Paralipomena in Vitellionem
- Desargues, Brouillon project
- Poncelet, Traite des proprietes projectives des figures

(Apologies for the lack of diacriticals, this phone does not allow for such).

Comment: You might find a more focused audience for this sort of question at the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) Q+A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an English translation of Desargues in Field and Gray's [*The Geometrical Work of Girard Desargues*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zSvSBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Hogendij's [*Desargues' Brouillon Project and the Conics of Apollonius*](http://www.jphogendijk.nl/publ/Desargues2.pdf) makes frequent reference to this book.

For Kepler, see Donahue's [translation](https://www.amazon.ca/Optics-Johannes-Kepler/dp/1888009128).